# Reportportal to JIRA integration not working

Tags: jira, reportportal

I am trying to setup reportportal on our network. When I logged in as superadmin and go to a project's bug tracking setup page, I don't see JIRA as an option.
But JIRA service is up (from docker ps command).

What are the gotchas to get it working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I checked health of docker services and ran "docker ps -a" followed by "docker logs ".
Then I started seeing JIRA as an option in bug tracking system.
I don't know why that made difference. It is strange!